# Google Maps Api Loading After DOM

Tags: api, google-maps, dom, loading

I'm having problems with the google maps api which is loading after the DOM, so when the
maps loads, the api didn't loaded yet and they aren't displayed. I've already tried to
use the getScript() jquery function and the asynchronous method.
Anybody have an ideia about what can I do for these maps work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load it in the `<head>`

```
<head>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=pt-BR"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you dude, it worked! The problem was that, in my Web Application, I was loading the api inside the body tag. Now, I'm loading it between the <head> </head> tags and it worked! Thanks a lot. (sorry any bad english)